# Find map location in google-maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm displaying a google map (v3) to my users, so that they can pan/zoom around the map and select a location (and zoom level). I can use `map.getZoom()` function to find zoom level set by user, but how can I have current location of the map set by user?

Comment: please define "select a location"

Comment: I mean user pans the map to his/her desired location, and I want to know lat/lon data for this location

Comment: How do you know where the desired location is placed inside the viewport? When you assume that it's placed in the middle use `map.getCenter()`

Comment: what does getCenter do? it gives center point of map? I think it is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: yes, it gives the center of the map. What do you want to achieve(do you want to store the viewport of the map)

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick! Can you please leave your comment as an answer so that I can confirm your answer?